# Django and related_name

Tags: django

first im so sorry with my english, im new with Django, im from php + codeigniter.

I have a problem with a `related_name`, the tables are fine, but the problem is that in the Select (DropDown) the data display is "bad", in this way: Tarifas_object:

Html code:

```
<option value="1">Tarifas object</option>
```

how ill display the correct data?

my model:

```
class Tarifas(models.Model):
    recarga = models.CharField(max_length=7, help_text='Codigo de la tarifa')
    precio = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    diligencias = models.PositiveIntegerField(max_length=3)

    def __inicode__(self):
        return self.precio 

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural="Tarifas"


class Recarga(models.Model):
    socio = models.ForeignKey(User)
    fecha = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    #valor = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2,verbose_name='Valor de la recarga', help_text= "Introduzca valores numericos ej.: 150.00")
    valor = models.ForeignKey(Tarifas, related_name='recarga_valor')
    diligencias = models.IntegerField(max_length=3, verbose_name='Cantidad de diligencias recargadas')
    tiponcf = models.IntegerField(max_length=1,choices=TIPO_NCF, verbose_name='Tipo de comprobante fiscal')
    ncf = models.CharField(max_length=19,verbose_name='Numero de comprobante fiscal')
    cajero = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    tipotarj = models.CharField(choices=TIPOS_TARJETAS, max_length=20, verbose_name='Tipo de tarjeta')
    numtarj = models.IntegerField(max_length=16, verbose_name='Numero de tarjeta')
    seguridad = models.IntegerField(max_length=3)
    forma_pago = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name='Forma de pago')
    banco = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    numerock = models.IntegerField(max_length=8, verbose_name='Numero de cheque')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s %s %s' % (self.socio,self.diligencias, self.fecha)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['socio']
```

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that's the straight copy and paste from your model, you've misspelled `unicode` on the Tarifas model.